# Debian Buster: Ngnix won't upgrade to 1.18, Conflicts: nginx-common

Tags: nginx, debian

After updating and upgrading all packages on the server, Nginx I can't get to update.

The Debian Buster package's Nginx is at 1.14, but I want to upgrade to the latest stable, 1.18, which isn't part of the Buster package at debian.org. So I added these lines to my sources.list:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ buster nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ buster nginx
```

I'm mediocre at Linux, so I might be using the wrong terms or don't understand the mechanics of upgrading.

`sudo apt upgrade nginx`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Conflicts: nginx-common but 1.14.2-2+deb10u3 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

`sudo apt --fix-broken install` doesn't help.

`apt-cache policy nginx`:

```
nginx:
  Installed: 1.14.2-2+deb10u3
  Candidate: 1.18.0-2~buster
  Version table:
     1.18.0-2~buster 500
        500 http://nginx.org/packages/debian buster/nginx amd64 Packages
     1.18.0-1~buster 500
        500 http://nginx.org/packages/debian buster/nginx amd64 Packages
     1.16.1-1~buster 500
        500 http://nginx.org/packages/debian buster/nginx amd64 Packages
     1.16.0-1~buster 500
        500 http://nginx.org/packages/debian buster/nginx amd64 Packages
 *** 1.14.2-2+deb10u3 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`sources.list` to which I added the last 2 nginx.org lines:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ buster nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ buster nginx
```

Comment: You're supposed to use `install` instead of `upgrade`. I was about to give an answer explaining this, but then saw that the current external nginx package has issues in its packaging dependencies anyway and this fails later (and even with tweaking, some config files get lost in the effort). My advice: remove and purge completely the current nginx packages, and  only then install the external nginx. Of course keep configuration backups before.

Comment: Ok, thanks A.B. By "issues in its packaging dependencies" do you mean the line mentioning nginx-common?

Comment: nope: this one happens when the correct command (install) is done: `trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package nginx-full 1.14.2-2+deb10u3` `dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)`